# Can a bash script access information from a C executable it takes as parameter?

Tags: c, bash, executable

To be more concrete, I have a C executable and I want to know in my bash script the execution time of a function from that C. I also want to know if I can find out what is the value of a certain variable from that file .

PS: I don't want to output on the console the things I need from the C file and then to read that output in the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Longer answer is no, but have a look at *profilers* to measure the execution time of a program (e.g. [gprof](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/)) and *debuggers* to inspect value of variables during runtime (e.g. [gdb](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Comment: Is there any way to find out when a function starts executing and when it stops? I want to find that timestamp obeying the restriction of not modifying the c source and only using the info I can get from the executable. I tried looking for this in gdb and gprof related articles, but i didn't found anything specific.